# (Asynchronous) database access POST

Tags: php, android, asynchronous, post

I am currently developing an android app that includes that has a login functionality. I have a database and a PHP-SignUp-script, that handles the database access, set up. When a user puts in his email address and password in, the Activity calls a method from its parent and passes the password over.

```
 public void checkCredentials(View view){
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String emailInput = ((EditText)(findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail))).getText().toString();
        String passwordInput = ((EditText)(findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword))).getText().toString();
        try {
            builder.append(URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8"));
            builder.append("=");
            builder.append(URLEncoder.encode(passwordInput, "UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String emailOutput = PostScreenActivity.dataBaseAccess("signIn", builder.toString());
 }
```

This method POSTs to the script and gets the username associated with the password back so it can return that to the caller method, which compares it to the username entered.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
try {
    URL url = new URL("https://database.de/url/to/script"+script+".php");
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
    osw.write(data);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader((new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream())));

    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
        builder.append(line);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return builder.toString();
```

I first had this in just a normal method but I it immediately crashed the app so I looked on SO, changed the app permissions and put all of it into an asynchronous subclass/inner class. Now the problem is that I have to access it from three different activities AND it needs to return the results to them and neither of those things seem possible with asynchronous task. I read everything I found online but there are so many different things being said and some are from so long ago that I am not sure what to do and how to approach this. Is a asynchronous task even the correct way of doing this? I really wanna do this right since it it handles something as important as login credentials..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a RESTful library such as HTTPClient (Apache) or Google's Volley library.

EDIT*
PS. When you say "securely", it is quite a large topic and using a well known library is at least recommended. HTTPS (a signed/certificated domain) is also recommended and now...somewhat required.

Google Volley / HTTPClient both happily use HTTP and HTTPs protocols leaving you with only a few lines of code to contend with...rather than writing your own implmentation which could have many holes!

[Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/) (My Preference for Android)
[Apache's HTTPClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) (My preference for backend java)

Comment: implemented it with Volley and it works like a charm. Thank you my friend!